# Is there any way to speed up this file I/O code?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app, I have about 300 `NSData` objects 0.5 MB in size, and I'm writing them all sequentially into a file with essentially this code (which writes a single 0.5 MB object 300 times):

```
- (void)createFile {

    // create .5 MB block to write
    int size = 500000;
    Byte *bytes = malloc(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        bytes[i] = 42;
    }
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:bytes length:size 
       freeWhenDone:YES];

    // temp output file
    NSUUID *uuid = [NSUUID UUID];
    NSString *path = [[NSTemporaryDirectory() 
        stringByAppendingPathComponent:[uuid UUIDString]] 
        stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"dat"];
    NSOutputStream *outputStream = [[NSOutputStream alloc] 
        initToFileAtPath:path append:NO];
    [outputStream open];

    double startTime = CACurrentMediaTime();

    NSInteger totalBytesWritten;
    NSInteger bytesWritten;
    Byte *readPtr;

    for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {

        // reset read pointer to block we're writing to the output
        readPtr = (Byte *)[data bytes];
        totalBytesWritten = 0;

        // write the block
        while (totalBytesWritten < size) {
            bytesWritten = [outputStream write:readPtr maxLength:size 
                - totalBytesWritten];
            readPtr += bytesWritten;
            totalBytesWritten += bytesWritten;
        }

    }

    double duration = CACurrentMediaTime() - startTime;
    NSLog(@"duration = %f", duration);

    [outputStream close];

}
```

On both my iPod (5th gen) and my iPhone 6, this process takes about 3 seconds, and I was wondering if there was any faster way to do this. I've tried using `NSFileManager` and `NSFileHandle` approaches, but they take about the same length of time, which leads me to suppose that this is a fundamental I/O limit I'm running into.

Is there any way to do this faster (this code should compile and run on any device)?

Comment: Not sure if you are running into this problem but you have a serious bug in your `while` loop. You need to replace `size` with `size - totalBytesWritten` in the call to `write:maxLength:`.

Comment: @rmaddy: thanks, nice catch. This isn't my actual code, but that bug was in my real method as well.

Comment: No I think the I/O bit is ok, however there is no need to use `malloc()`; just use `NSMutableData` instead.

Comment: It slow coz you're writing a single byte at a time and without any buffers.

Comment: @TienDinh no he's not.

Comment: Have you tried [dispatch_io_create](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_io_create) + [dispatch_io_write](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_io_write)?

Comment: @Sega-Zero: I'm going to give that a try, thanks.

Comment: @MusiGenesis please, describe your experience with dispatch i/o, did it make things any better?

Comment: @std.denis: no, it seems to be the same or worse. I couldn't get the code to create a new file with it to work. The only thing I got working was to write the 300 buffers into an already-existing file with dispatch_io_write. This would have been OK for my purposes, but it took the same amount of time as the code in my original post here. So I really seem to be running into a fundamental I/O limit here, but I'm posting a bounty in the hopes that someone can prove me wrong.

Comment: I think the issue here is the sheer number of syscalls and context changes. I'd try using mmap to map the whole address space wanted into memory and write to that

Comment: I would say you are I/O bound as you are writing 47 MB/s (400mb/s).

Comment: Not sure if this'll speed it up but it's worth a try. Just after the loops put, 'for(int i = 0; i < 300; i++) { @autoreleasepool{ ...}  }'

Answer (score 4):

Here's the highest performance I was able to achieve, using mmap & memcpy.

It takes on average about 0.2 seconds to run on my iPhone 6, with some variation up to around 0.5s. YMMV, however, as it would appear that the iPhone 6 has two different flash storage providers - one is TLC and the other is MLC - those with TLC will get significantly better results.

This of course assumes that you are OK with async I/O. If you truly need something synchronous, look for other solutions.

```
- (IBAction)createFile {
  NSData *data = [[self class] dataToCopy];

  // temp output file
  NSUUID *uuid = [NSUUID UUID];
  NSString *path = [[NSTemporaryDirectory()
                     stringByAppendingPathComponent:[uuid UUIDString]]
                    stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"dat"];

  NSUInteger size = [data length];
  NSUInteger count = 300;

  NSUInteger file_size = size * count;

  int fd = open([path UTF8String], O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
  ftruncate(fd, file_size);

  void *addr = mmap(NULL, file_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

  double startTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
  static dispatch_queue_t concurrentDataQueue;
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    concurrentDataQueue = dispatch_queue_create("test.concurrent", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
  });

  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    dispatch_async(concurrentDataQueue, ^{
      memcpy(addr + (i * size), [data bytes], size);
    });
  }

  dispatch_barrier_async(concurrentDataQueue, ^{
    fsync(fd);

    double duration = CACurrentMediaTime() - startTime;
    NSLog(@"duration = %f", duration);

    munmap(addr, file_size);
    close(fd);
    unlink([path UTF8String]);
  });
}
```

Comment: Sure you are writing ~500K each time? Your numbers suggest a write rate of 300-750 MB/s which seems high relative to the benchmarks out there for the iPhone 6 flash memory. Great if its right.

Comment: I'm trying out your method here. What include/import statements do I need for the PROT_READ, PROT_WRITE and MAP_SHARED constants?

Comment: So this code does not seem to be working, not sure if I'm doing something wrong. In my real-world application, this approach is only slightly faster than my original method (about 4 seconds vs. 4.5 seconds), and something seems to be wrong with the file creation process. If I use NSFileManager to check the file's size after calling munmap, close and unlink, it's returning a file size of 0. And my code which is attempting to read this file crashes since it's a zero-length file at that point.

Comment: Er, it's not zero-length, the file doesn't exist at that point: "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory". I see that you're calling `unlink` at the end of all this - should there be a matching `link` call somewhere?

Comment: Did you include the call to ftruncate? That is very important

Comment: Also unlink actually deletes the file from disk, so only call that if you want it deleted.

Comment: Aha, the unlink is what was deleting the file (I was calling ftruncate). If I comment out the unlink, the method works as expected. Problem is that I'm definitely not seeing .2 to .5 seconds for this. The whole operation is taking about 4 seconds (vs. 4.5 to 5 seconds with my original code), so definitely faster but not orders of magnitude faster like what you're seeing.

Comment: I don't know if this would affect things, but in my real code the 300+ NSData objects are real, so the app's memory usage is up around 170 MB+. Would that kind of memory pressure maybe be slowing down these operations somehow?

Comment: Related question: for no particular reason, I'm attempting to make this operation write-only, swapping `O_RDWR` for `O_WRONLY` and `PROR_WRITE` for `PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE`, but I get a bad access crash this way. Is there even any reason to try to make this write-only?

Comment: Write-only won't have any real-world performance benefits unless you have multiple processes trying to modify the same file, no. The only time i've needed to do write-only mapping is when dealing with OpenGL buffers.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: is there something about this code that would be fundamentally blocking? I'm finding that this code is locking up my UI until it's completed, even though I'm calling it via `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(`.

Comment: @MusiGenesis memcpy will eat your CPU(s), because this is a parallel queue. Consider using a serial queue if you absolutely need the UI thread.

Comment: Technically for small files this does not make much sense?

Answer (score 2):

300 * 0.5 / 3 = 50MB/s for 150MB of data looks fast enough. I suppose you hit the flash storage WRITE speed limit. I believe you run this code in a background thread, so the issue is not in blocking of UI

Comment: 50mb/s is extremely slow for a flash storage

Comment: It is bytes not bits. So it is 47.68 MB/s or 400 mb/s. I would say you are most likey I/O bound.

Comment: 50MB/s write would be slow for a desktop or laptop SSD. It doesn't seem totally unreasonable for a phone (where power efficiency is especially prioritized).

Answer (score 2):

Two performance tips that I can recommend are: try turning off file-system caching or checking the IO buffer size.

"When reading data that you are certain you won’t need again soon, such as streaming a large multimedia file, tell the file system not to add that data to the file-system caches.

Apps can call the BSD `fcntl` function with the `F_NOCACHE` flag to enable or disable caching for a file. For more information about this function, see `fcntl`."~[Performance Tips](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTips/PerformanceTips.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH7-SW1)

or "read much or all of the data into memory before processing it" ~[Performance Tips](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTips/PerformanceTips.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH7-SW1)

iPhone 6 uses 16Gb SK hynix flash storage~[[Teardown]](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iPhone+6+Plus+Teardown/29206) and the theoretical limit for sequential write is around 40 to 70 Mb/s~[[NAND flash]](https://www.skhynix.com/gl/products/nand.jsp).